# django after submit javascript handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

I have a form which successfully sends data to my view which in turn returns a JSON object, I have a corresponding template containing AJAX which gets invoked after submitting the data to the server, however when printing out the data it seems to be just the template HTML code, not the JSON sent, is there anything I am doing which is obviously wrong?

```
<body>
    <form action="." method="post" id="myform">{% csrf_token %}
         {{ myform.as_p }}
        <p>Date: <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date"></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date"></p>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" name="my_form" id="my_form"></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

corresponding ajax

```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   error: function() {
      $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
   },
   success: function(data) {
       alert( data)
   },
   type: 'get'
  })
```

view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        my_form = GraphForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            response = {
                        'status':str(my_form.cleaned_data['my_form']),                       }

            obj = {"a": "SHELL", "b": "ghost"}
            return render(request,"mysite/index.html", obj,content_type="application/json" )

        else:
            form = GraphForm()
            return render(request,"mysite/index.html", { 'form' : form } )
    else:
        form = GraphForm()
        return render(request,"mysite/index.html", { 'form' : form }  )
```

Comment: sounds like ajax, I'm using jQuery for this, google "jquery ajax example"

Comment: thanks, i have updated the above, but i just get baffling errors, any insight into this?

Comment: What are the specific errors you are getting when you say you're getting "bafflng errors"?

Comment: well I just checked through my debugger, the server code gets invoked, so does the ajax, however when i print out the successful data retrieved it seems to be just the HTML of the template not the JSON

Comment: plz add view which handles this url ... note -  better get url from data-url attribute

Comment: done, the view definitely gets invoked, let me know if you need anything else